# Rotating UILabels from any position to upright

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a label that I rotate using

```
pieceBlack.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((M_PI * (180) / 180.0));
```

and that works perfectly, EXCEPT:

I rotate this label during the game to either right side up or upside down.  How do I say, "**Whatever angle you are at, go back to upright."**  I'm thinking maybe like an:

```
int PreviousAngle = ?;
pieceBlack.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(0-PreviousAngle));
```

so I guess what I'm asking is how you ask for the rotation angle. Or, alternately, maybe there is a sort of

```
pieceBlack.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(RotateToUpright);
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I remember transform is always relative from the upright position (original), so `0.0f`? So you can just do `pieceBlack.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity`

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to first position the (in my case) view in the "straight up" orientation.  Then I used the CGAffineTransformMakeRotation to create the somewhat off-kilter view.  Finally, I applied the identity transform to bring the view back to its straight-up position.

Answer (score 0):

you don't want to **set** the transform, you want to **modify** it,

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(view.transform, angle);
```

if you need to keep the old one around, then do